# Calling script to clear cookies on specific site in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, background

I'm trying to create chrome extension which check if site contains specific element, then clear cookies for this site and refresh.

I created sample extension to delete cookies but in background.js using event `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`, :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    var url = tab.url;
    var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
    var d = matches && matches[1].replace('www.','');
    d = '.'+d;

    chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: d}, function (cookies) {

        for (var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) {
            var url = "http" + (cookies[i].secure ? "s" : "") + "://" + cookies[i].domain + cookies[i].path;
            var cname = cookies[i].name;

            chrome.cookies.remove({
                "url": url,
                "name": cname
            });
        }

        chrome.tabs.reload();
    });
});
```

I took this code from one of posts on stackoverflow, and I was trying to transform it for my need.

In my main extension in background.js I have:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'script.js'});
});
});
```

and then in script.js:

```
..some code...
var test = document.getElementById('u_0_c');
         if (test === null || test.innerText == "") {
            /*------------------------------*/
              HERE I WANT TO CLEAR COOKIES
            /*----------------------------*/
         }
..some code...
```

I can't use there my code to clear cookies because I got errors like:
`Cannot read property 'getSelected' of undefined` and similiars.

Thanks for every help ;)

Comment: Without manifest.json I can only guess that by "main extension" you mean the browserAction popup (actually there are no main or non-main parts as every part is meaningful), in which case the problem is that the onClicked listener won't run if you have default_popup declared in manifest.json. Either move that function inner contents into the popup script (if you need to show the UI) or remove default_popup (if you don't need to show a popup). Next, the getSelected error means you're running the code in a content script, which cannot use chrome.tabs API by design.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hm, I think you didn't understand me, I have main extension with popup, content script etc, where I want to clear cookies but not onClicked, and I created sample extension without popup, just click to clear and I attached code. I want to change code to clear cookies to execute on specific site not onClicked.
I got this error when I tried to put this code from sample extension in getSelected function inside script.js which is executing on site from background.js in my 'main' extension

Comment: I guessed wrong. Please add manifest.json so we don't have to guess blindly.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
          
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Main extension",
  "author": "Ar1st0v",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum",
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
  "permissions": [
     "cookies",
     "activeTab",
     "browsingData",
     "storage",
     "unlimitedStorage",
     "tabs",
     "<all_urls>",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}

Comment: Looks like my initial guess was correct after all.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah with that i can't use chrome.tabs API in content script but do you have some ideas how can I do what I want? I can make this code in background.js but I have to use DOM in my script

Comment: Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to coordinate the content script and the background script.